# If $f_n{\rightarrow} f $ uniformly and $f$ is bounded then prove that $f_n^{2}{\rightarrow}f^{2} $ uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_n{\rightarrow} f $ uniformly and $f$ is bounded, how can we prove that $f_n^{2}{\rightarrow}f^{2} $ uniformly? I am revising for my analysis final and got stuck on this problem, any help is really appreciated.

Comment: yes uniformly, i forgot to put that in>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use the fact that $f$ is bounded and $f_n\to f$ uniformly to show that there is a uniform bound $M>0$ such that $|f_n(x)|<M$ and $|f(x)|<M$ for all $n$ and all $x$.
2. You can use the identity $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ to bound the difference of squares in terms of $M$ and the difference of the original functions.

Comment: Thanks, got it! if u have time, can you also look at one other problem i posted,thanks!http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253434/if-non-vanishing-never-0-f-n-rightarrow-f-uniformly-then-1-f-n-rightarr

Answer (score 0):

I think more assumptions are needed if you mean $f_n\rightarrow f$ in the pointwise sense. A counter-example is taking $f_n$ to be the positive spike of height 1 and width $2/n$ centred at $x=1/n$ and zero outside $(0,2/n)$. This function tends to zero pointwise whilst the sup of its square is always 1.

Comment: It's true if $f_n\to f$ uniformly, which is probably intended (unless it was a "prove or disprove" type problem).  Edit: The question has been updated to state the hypothesis that $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f_n^2-f^2=(f_n-f)(f_n+f)$.