# If non vanishing (never 0) $f_n{\rightarrow} f $ uniformly then $1/f_n{\rightarrow}1/f $ uniformly. Prove or give a counterexample.

Tags: real-analysis

I came up with the counterexample $f_n = 1/n$ such that it converges uniformly to $f=0$ but I am not sure that its a good one because $1/f$ is not defined.           Do you think its a good counterexample? Can anyone come up with another one?

Thanks!

Comment: Better pack all [your exercise problems for the same topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253410/if-f-n-rightarrow-f-uniformly-andf-is-bounded-then-prove-that-f-n2-r) in one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the limit of $\frac1{f_n}$ does not even exist, I would consider this a fine counterexmple.
On the other hand, what about $f_n\colon (0,1)\to\mathbb R$, $x\mapsto x+\frac1n$? Then the reciprocal of the limit *does* exist, but the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: are u sure the convergence is not uniform, it seems a little annoying to prove that? did you do it?

Comment: @UH1: The pointwise limit $\frac 1x$ is not bounded, but all $\frac1{f_n}$ are.

Comment: @UH1: It also isn't hard to show directly that for each $n$ there exists $x$ such that $\left|\dfrac{1}{f(x)}−\dfrac{1}{f_n(x)}\right|>1$.